# Wordpress theme core files not reflecting changes when edited as child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I concluded to use a theme called MagazineNP for a site project, created the child theme with necessary files and could edit safely and the result pops up.

For the past 4days I've had an issue with the theme core files, when I copy it to my child theme to get it edited and saved, It wont show up on site but It shows if I edited it via the parent theme...

Please help, I'm still a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you a little list of tips first they are pretty basic but always help when nothing else does:

1. Clean your browser cache
2. If you have included some cache plugins flush the website cache
3. Review if the theme has any function to disallow changes in child-theme
4. Review if the theme has any optimization function enable and turn it off
5. One you have tried all this and nothing works enable the child theme again and do a simple edit put some echo code in the `PHP` file or an `HTML` tag and see if this works or don't

Comment: I've tried your option 1,2.... I realised that it was the files in the core folder of the theme I couldnt edit as child theme, when i edited the header and footer in the theme's root folder which where not in the core folder, I could make changes to them and it would reflect on the website.

Comment: I don't know where theme you were using but basically, when you want to edit some part you must copy in your child theme folder before editing, at least it is the proper way to do it because when you update your theme if you make some edit in any file in the parent theme it is gone

Comment: I think you are facing cache issue, so use incognito mode in browser.